# MySQL Workbench EER diagram: edges of display cut off

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm having an issue where the edges of the display are cut off when viewing an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench:

[image]

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04. I've tried the following already:

- Resizing the window
- Changing display resolution (default is 1920 x 1080, I tried reducing to 1680 x 1050)
- Changing display scale (default is 100%, I tried 125%)
- Setting environment variable GDK_SCALE=1 on startup

When I run from the command line, everything looks fine until I open EER diagram, at which point I get this output:

`(mysql-workbench-bin:13508): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:01:10.921: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed`

This is what my wb.1.log file looks like:

```
    base dir: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    plugin path: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/plugins
    struct path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/grt
    module path: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules
    library path: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries
    user data dir: /home/shura/.mysql/workbench
    open at start: 
    open type: 
    run at startup: 
    run type: 
    Force SW rendering: No
    Force OpenGL: No
    quit when done: No
15:05:22 [INF][      WBContext]: WbContext::init
15:05:22 [INF][            WBA]: Looking for extension modules for WBA...
15:05:22 [INF][            WBA]: 0 extension modules found
15:05:22 [WRN][            grt]: Duplicate plugin name wb.tools.cmdlineClient   There is more than one plugin with the name wb.tools.cmdlineClient (in PyWbUtils and PyWbUtils).
15:05:22 [WRN][            grt]: /home/shura/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml:23: link 'f4a743c2-498c-11ec-b08f-f34455d9e052' <object GrtObject> key=owner could not be resolved
15:05:22 [WRN][            grt]: Duplicate plugin name wb.tools.cmdlineClient   There is more than one plugin with the name wb.tools.cmdlineClient (in PyWbUtils and PyWbUtils).
15:05:22 [INF][      WBContext]: System info:
    MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 8.0.27 CE build 1228725 (64 bit)
    Configuration Directory: /home/shura/.mysql/workbench
    Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
    Cairo Version: 1.16.0
    OS: Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64
    CPU: 16x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700K CPU @ 3.80GHz (3800.000MHz) - 31.14GiB RAM
No video adapter info available
    Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

    Fips mode enabled: no
```

I've tried googling the warnings, and haven't found anything that points me in an obvious direction. Grateful for any advice!

Comment: Hi Shura, Did you manage to find a solution for the problem?

Comment: No, and I actually no longer use MySLQ.

Answer (score 0):

There should be draggable resizing arrows on the borders of the panels from the center out.
Navigator panel and the whole left side have it on the right edge of the navigator panel.
Likewise, Templates panel and the whole right side has it on the left side of the panel itself.